# Rowspan and alignment issue

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi, Attached is the image of the popup where in I'm using rowspan for alignment. Still am not getting the proper alignment.

Here is the Css and MArkup tags. ALL the text boxes shld be left aligned with uniform space between them.

```
<div id="divDownload" runat="server" visible="true">
        <dx:aspxpopupcontrol id="pcDownload" runat="server" showpagescrollbarwhenmodal="true"
            clientinstancename="pcDownload" enableclientsideapi="true" modal="True" popuphorizontalalign="WindowCenter"
            popupverticalalign="WindowCenter" showheader="false" allowdragging="True" enableanimation="False"
             width="600px" autoupdateposition="true" closeaction="CloseButton" visible="true" OnClientClick="">
                        <ContentCollection>
                            <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl4" runat="server"
                                Width="100%">
                                <dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel3" runat="server">
                                    <PanelCollection>
                                        <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent4" runat="server">
                                            <div>
                                                <table class="cChildTable">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <h3>Download</h3>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="auto-style1">
                                                            <div class="hr">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDownLoadMessages" runat="server" CssClass="cMessageArea"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="cChildTable" border="0">
                                                    <tr><td style="font:bold" colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text="Content Link Title"></asp:Label></td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;" rowspan="8">
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkImg" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="true"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td rowspan="3" Style="vertical-align:top">
                                                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" Width="80px" Height="80px" Style="top: 0px;" AlternateText="No Image" />                       
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td  style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkName" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td  style="vertical-align: top;width:10%">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>                    
                                                    </tr> 
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCompany" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text="Company:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddress" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:"  CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>                                                  
                                                    <tr>
                                                         <td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:center; padding-top:0.25em"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddImg" runat="server" Text="Add" target="_blank"> </asp:LinkButton></td>              
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtyStateZip" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:auto">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCtyStateZip" runat="server" Text="City, State Zip:" Width="77px" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCtyStateZip" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPhone" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFax" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFax" runat="server" Text="Fax:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFax" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEmail" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                        </td>                                                     
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblOther" runat="server" Text="Other:" Width="90px" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5">
                                                            <div class="buttons">
                                                                <span id="span2" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span class="cBtnRight">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDownLoad" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Download"
                                                                       OnClick="btnDownLoad_Click"/>
                                                                </span></span></span><span id="span1" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span
                                                                    class="cBtnRight">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Cancel"
                                                                        Visible="true" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                                                                </span></span></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                             </div>
                                            </dx:PanelContent>
                                        </PanelCollection>
                                    </dx:ASPxPanel>
                                </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                                </ContentCollection>
             </dx:aspxpopupcontrol>    
    </div>



 CSSClass for .clabeltext
    .cLabelText { 
    border-right:none;
    height:19px;
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size:9pt;
    text-align: left !important;
    color:#464646;
    font-weight:normal;
    width:2px;
}
.cTextSearch{ /* Using TextBox Style Old Name RDFormText*/
    clear:both;
    padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;
    height:19px;
    border:1px solid #cdc9c9;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #464646; /* previous light color color:#959595; */
    text-align:left;
    resize: none;   
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "uniform space" ?

Comment: The height between the fields Name and company is more compared to fields of Fax and Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                                 <td  style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkName" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td  style="vertical-align: top;width:10%">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
```

Remove `style="vertical-align: top;"` from this code

because it's only aligned the checkbox, name textbox in top of the row.. the default is alignment is middle, so you just remove the style `vertical-align:top` for those elements ... That's all

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `rowspan=5` with `Add` link and add it under the logo image and keep the `rowspan=8` for logo cell. Update your table like below.

```
  <table class="cChildTable" border="0">
                                                <tr><td style="font:bold" colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text="Content Link Title"></asp:Label></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;" rowspan="8">
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkImg" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="true"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td rowspan="8" Style="vertical-align:top">
                                                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" Width="80px" Height="80px" Style="top: 0px;" AlternateText="No Image" />
 <div  style="text-align:center; padding-top:0.25em"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddImg" runat="server" Text="Add" target="_blank"> </asp:LinkButton></div>                     
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td  style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkName" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td  style="vertical-align: top;width:10%">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>                    
                                                </tr> 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCompany" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text="Company:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddress" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address:"  CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                                  
                                                <tr>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtyStateZip" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width:auto">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCtyStateZip" runat="server" Text="City, State Zip:" Width="77px" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCtyStateZip" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="300px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPhone" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFax" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFax" runat="server" Text="Fax:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFax" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEmail" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server" Checked="true"
                                                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                    </td>                                                     
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblOther" runat="server" Text="Other:" Width="90px" CssClass="cLabelText"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" CssClass="cText" Width="150px" MaxLength="75"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="5">
                                                        <div class="buttons">
                                                            <span id="span2" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span class="cBtnRight">
                                                                <asp:Button ID="btnDownLoad" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Download"
                                                                   OnClick="btnDownLoad_Click"/>
                                                            </span></span></span><span id="span1" class="cBtnLeft"><span class="cBtnMid"><span
                                                                class="cBtnRight">
                                                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Width="65px" CssClass="cBtnRight" Text="Cancel"
                                                                    Visible="true" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                                                            </span></span></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: Thank you Suresh, except not able to set td width for labels

Comment: why? you can assign width easily. Try to assign width in pixels or assign percentage width for all the cells.